# How do I carry out AES Encryption in javascript and decrypt the result in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, aes

I have a JavaScript frontend that's meant to encrypt data using AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding and send to a Java backend for decryption.

This is an extract of my JavaScript code:

```js
export const encryptPaymentData = (data) => {
  var encrypt = new JSEncrypt()
  encrypt.setPublicKey(publicKey)

  // convert the JSON object to a string
  const jsonDataString = JSON.stringify(data)

  // Create iv and secret_key
  let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)
  let secret_key = crypto.randomBytes(32)

  // iv = Buffer.from(iv).toString("base64")
  // secret_key = Buffer.from(secret_key).toString("base64")

  iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(iv))
  secret_key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(
    CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(secret_key)
  )

  // Encrypt the plaintext using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
  console.log("iv", iv)
  console.log("Secret", secret_key)
  const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(jsonDataString, secret_key, {
    iv: iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  })
  console.log("cipherText", ciphertext)

  // Print the ciphertext
  console.log(ciphertext.toString())
}
```

And this is an extract of my Java code:

```java
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";

public String decryptAES(String ciphertext, String secretKey, String iv) throws Exception {
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(iv));
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(secretKey), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM, "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(ciphertext));
        return new String(decrypted);
    }
```

When I copy the secret key and iv and encrypted value and try to decrypt in my Java program, I keep getting an error: `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted`

Please, what could the problem be?

Comment: The CryptoJS code is inconsistent. You generate a random 32 bytes key, but then pass it as a Base64 encoded string. Therefore CryptoJS uses a key derivation function. This is probably not intended, since such a key can be used directly. For this it has to be passed as WordArray. So you should fix the CryptoJS code first. By the way, CryptoJS has its own PRNG: `CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random()` i.e. the crypto module of NodeJS is not needed at all. The combination of both probably does not work either.

Comment: Not happy with the encryption provided by https?

Comment: Also the IV should be passed as WordArray. The Base64 encoding of the key and IV should only be used for the output. Furthermore, a public RSA key is imported at the beginning, which is not used in the rest of the code. What is this about?

Comment: `meant to encrypt data and send to backend for decryption` -  I'd better challenge this design as unnecessary complexity. what kind of attacks would this design prevent your users from? save your time and don't implement useless things...

Comment: Hi ursa, the design is meant to simulate sending card details from a javascript frontend to a java (likely spring boot) backend. The regulators we're working with are insisting that some form of encryption be used to concel card information when sending

Comment: Hi Topaco, you were right! Thanks! I followed your instructions and everything is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Topaco's explanation, I passed the secret_key and iv as WordArray not Base64, and that resolved the issue.

```
function encrypt(data) {
  // convert the JSON object to a string
  const jsonDataString = JSON.stringify(data);

  // Create iv and secret_key
  let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  let secret_key = crypto.randomBytes(32);

  iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(iv);
  secret_key = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(secret_key);

  // Encrypt the plaintext using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
  const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(jsonDataString, secret_key, {
    iv: iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  });
  console.log("cipherText", ciphertext);

  // Print the ciphertext
  console.log(ciphertext.toString());
}
```